# How to add CheckBox, Label and DDL to ASP.NET page programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add a check box, label and DDL to ASP.NET page (aspx) from my back class in C#. I have been using  `LiteralControl _liText = new LiteralControl();` to attach label so that I can show them using `this.Controls.Add(_liText);`in CreateChildControls() method.

How do I add DDL and check box to ASp.NET page from C# code so that my label is in the same line with DDL and checkbox?

I have already made DDL using this syntax:

```
List<DropDownList> _ddlCollection=new List<DropDownList>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                _ddlCollection.Add(new DropDownList());
            }
```

Problem is not in this.Controls.Add() which I call from CreateChildControls(). It is OnPreRender() method where I fill ddl and check box. Is LiteralControl class good for  this? Here is what I have tried in OnPReRender():

```
 foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
            {
                if (!list.Hidden)
                {
                    _liText.Text += @<input type="checkbox">;
                    _liText.Text += list.Title + "<br />";

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should add a placeholder.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phMain"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</form>
```

Next, if you have add in one line you use table (It is a simple but not recommended method,  next step add all to Page and set css style for the page).

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    base.CreateChildControls();
    Table table = new Table();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();

        TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
        tc1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(String.Format("Line {0}",i)));
        tr.Cells.Add(tc1);

        TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
        CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
        chb.ID = String.Format("CheckBox_{0}", i);
        chb.Text = String.Format("CheckBox {0}", i);
        chb.CheckedChanged += chb_CheckedChanged;
        chb.AutoPostBack = true;
        tc2.Controls.Add(chb);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc2);

        TableCell tc3 = new TableCell();
        DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
        ddl.ID = String.Format("DropDownList_{0}", i);
        ddl.Items.Add("1111");
        ddl.Items.Add("2222");
        ddl.Items.Add("3333");
        ddl.SelectedIndex = i;
        ddl.Enabled = false;
        tc3.Controls.Add(ddl);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc3);


        table.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
    phMain.Controls.Add(table);
}

void chb_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox chb = sender as CheckBox;
    string ddlid = chb.ID.Replace("CheckBox", "DropDownList");
    DropDownList ddl = this.Page.FindControl(ddlid) as DropDownList;
    if (ddl != null)
    {
        ddl.Enabled = chb.Checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you not use a table with forms as that is semantically incorrect. Tables are for tabular data.

Comment: Can you tell me how to connect Event with each of the checkboxes. Ther is no OnItemChecked method in intelisense

Answer (score 2):

Your controls exist but the page or user control are not aware of them.

You need to add your control to the page

```
Page.Controls.Add(_ddlCollection);
```

You can also add your controls to other controls on the page, for example a panel.

```
panel1.Controls.Add(_ddlCollection);
```

You are adding a list of dropdowns which I don't think is what you want.
You need to add ListItems instead.

```
var dropDown = new DropDownList {Id = "dropDown1"};
dropDown.Items.Add(new ListItem("text", "value");

Page.Controls.Add(dropDown);
```

Add a label for the dropdown.

```
Page.Controls.Add(new Label {AssociatedControlId = dropDown.Id, Text = "Drop me down"});
```

For your other controls follow the same process:

**Add a checkbox**
Don't add an html control to a literal unless that is really what you want. 
If you want to be able to access that checkbox in the code behind then you need to add it as an asp.net control. User a placeholder.

```
placeHolder1.Controls.Add(new CheckBox {Id = "chkBox", Text="Tick me"});
```

The text property on the checkbox will be the label for the check box and tick/untick the check box when you click on the text.

Output should be

```
<label for="dropDown1" >Drop me down</label>
<select id="dropDown1" >
    <option value="value" >text</option>
</select>    

<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" />
<label for="chkbox" >Tick me</label>
```